Results from table differs from view
I currently have an issue where there are data discrepancies between a view that is then used in a union all view. The source of truth is view1.
We then create a 'joint' view (view3), union all between view1 and view2. It has to be a union since the views get data from two different sources.
But what I have found is that when I sum the values from view3 using where MASTER_TENANT = 'View1_Master_Tentant', the data differs from what it is when I sum it directly from view1.
Below is a sample of the query to create view3. I'm really at my wits' end and can't figure out why the data for view1 suddenly is different.
create or replace view3
copy grants
as

select
    MEGS_USED,
    MINUTES_USED,
    SMS,
    MMS,
    USSD,
    date_trunc(month, USAGE_DATE) as USAGE_MONTH,
    'View1_Master_Tenant' as MASTER_TENANT
FROM VIEW1 as v1
WHERE
    u.USAGE_DATE::DATE >= '2023-07-01'
    and u.MASTER_TENANT = 'Tenant1'

union all

select
    MEGS_USED,
    MINUTES_USED,
    SMS,
    MMS,
    USSD,
    date_trunc(month, USAGE_DATE) as USAGE_MONTH,
    'View2_Master_Tenant' as MASTER_TENANT
FROM VIEW1 as v2
WHERE
    u.USAGE_DATE::DATE >= '2023-07-01'
    and u.MASTER_TENANT = 'Tenant2';


What does GROUP BY ALL do here?

Sorry. That was not supposed to be in there. I use it when I do the sum. I edited my post.

Hi - your SQL doesn’t contain a UNION (typo?). If you create view3 as just the select from view1 do they then give the same result? If so then you know it’s something to do with the union

Sorry about that. I left that part out. Post is updated. I don't understand why there is the difference.

Can you also provide the queries that you are running that aren't working out the way you expect them to?  You post isn't clear on what you are seeing as an issue.

I think I might have figured out one potential issue. I want to test my theory. If that doesn't work, I'll post the queries.
